# Pictures vertical aligned, with vertical aligned caption side by side and configurable horizontal space

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, captions, sidebyside

i have already searched the internet and the forum for a solution, but unfortunately no post applies to my requests. Also the merging of different posts didn't work out.

The goal is:

1. 2 png-graphics side by side (here is already the first problem: one is about 703x775 pixel, the other about 1032x493 pixel)
2. below both graphics there should be one caption each (one shorter, the other longer)
3. both captions should be at the same height
4. at the same time the 1032x493 image should be centered and have an adjustable distance to the other image
5. A third global caption for both images should currently not be included, but can be added at any time (so no subcaptions with a) and b), but rather with "Figure X1" and "FigureX2")
6. Nevertheless, both images should be adjustable in size

Unfortunately either the captions always shift vertically or the right image is too low or no distance between the images can be adjusted. It would be very nice of you if you can help me =) The following code is my current state:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, paper=a4]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}[b][][t]{0.38\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pictureLeft.png} 
            \caption{Möglicherweise kurzer Text}
        \end{minipage}
        \hspace*{.02\linewidth}
        \begin{minipage}[b][][t]{0.48\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pictureRight.png}
            \caption{Langer Text, der sich über mehrere Zeilen erstreckt und die Überschrift aktuell verschiebt\cite{}}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please add a sketch of the desired layout to your question? Does replacing `\begin{minipage}[b][][t]` by `\begin{minipage}[t][][t]` give your the desired result? See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSluR.png)

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBRqS.png

This is the desired layout. Unfortunately the option switching from \begin{minipage}[b][][t] to \begin{minipage}[t][][t] didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, paper=a4]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[demo,  % in real document remove this option
            export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=c]{pictureLeft.png}
    &
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=5cm,valign=c]{pictureRight.png} \\
%
\caption{Möglicherweise kurzer Text}
    &
\caption{Langer Text, der sich über mehrere Zeilen erstreckt und die Überschrift aktuell verschiebt\cite{}}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**addendum:** alternative solution, which enable simple adjustment of image size with kept image aspect ratio is:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, paper=a4]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{} p{0.4\dimexpr\linewidth-\tabcolsep}
                                  p{0.6\dimexpr\linewidth-\tabcolsep}}
\includegraphics[valign=c]{example-image-duck}
    &
\includegraphics[valign=c]{example-image-duck} \\
%
\caption{Möglicherweise kurzer Text}
    &
\caption{Langer Text, der sich über mehrere Zeilen erstreckt und die Überschrift aktuell verschiebt\cite{}}
    \end{tabular*}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution works, i have only a few questions:

 1. what kind of column/option is this? : {*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}<br/>              
 2. is it possible to adjust the gap between the images?<br/>
 3. when i do \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=5cm,valign=c]{pictureRight.png}, the picture is a little bit distorted, is there a possibility to scale the images, leaving the ratio the same?

Comment: @Joey, (i)  `>{\centering\arraybackslash}X` is modified `X` column type in which cells' contents horizontally centered. (ii) `*{2}{...}` means two equal column types, (iii) i don't understand what you mean with "distorted" (iv) for details of image settings (`width`, `height`, `trim`, `keepaspectrtio` see documentation for `graphicx` package (it is part of your LaTeX installation). The image `height` is select only to show, how figure will looks if images are not equally high In case that you like to have different with of image, than you can change table specification. see edited answer.

Comment: Distorted meant only that i want to keep the ratio of each image, bad translation sorry^^ thanks a lot for the examples and detailled explanations, you saved my day!

Comment: @Joey, does answer solve your problem? if it so, you can accept it by clicking on the check mark at the top left side of answer :-)

Comment: Good point, thank you :-)